# SSAS error at processing

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am a beginner in SSAS and as I tried to process a dimension it fails and I get this error:

> " Erreur OLE DB : "Erreur OLE DB ou ODBC : Login failed for user
>   'AUTORITE NT\SERVICE RÉSEAU'.; 28000. "

I tried creating a new login and in user mapping i marked the database I need and marked the role db_owner along with public, but it still didn't work

I tried using a windows account and I get this:

> "Erreur OLE DB : Erreur OLE DB ou ODBC : A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.;
>   08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not
>   supported on the client.; 08001."

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Data Sources', double click your current data source and go to 'Impersonation Information' tab. Here, by default 'Use the service account' option will be selected. Change that to 'Use a specific Windows user name and password'. Then, enter the Windows credentials of a user who has access to the data source. Now proceed with the processing.